# How do you open a zipx file on a Mac/Linux?

Tags: linux, macos

I've got some files for a project that's due in a few weeks. The guy sent them in a zipx file. How would I extract the files from a zipx on OS X or Linux?

Comment: I would really like to.

Answer (score 5):

The Unarchiver v2.3 will do, except for compressed jpeg within the zipx archive.

Comment: It's up to v3.2 now, and claims full zipx support as of 3.0.

Answer (score 1):

[ZipX](http://www.zipxfile.com/) is an advanced Zip compression format [introduced by WinZip](http://www.winzip.com/ovwc17/prodpagewz.htm).  It appears there's only a few commercial utilities that support it.

OSX users can use [Stuffit Deluxe 2009 for Mac](http://my.smithmicro.com/win/stuffit/index.html) ($50 USD) to decompress these files.  (The [zipxfile.com](http://www.zipxfile.com/) claims Stuffit Deluxe can do it, but I actually don't see that specified on the Stuffit site, so look carefully before buying.)

Aside from that, I'd recommend requesting the files in a more standard archive format.  Neither RAR nor 7zip archivers support ZipX yet.

Comment: comment from [David De](http://superuser.com/users/19295/david-de): Not sure if the demo version is supposed to allow you to extract a zipx file, but it didn't let me. This is on a G4 Powerbook running 10.5.8

Comment: comment from [Rbehymer](http://superuser.com/users/32635/rbehymer): Just tried Stuffit Expander 2010, no luck expanding a client's zipx file. Client tried opening her own file, had no problems, so corrupt file isn't the problem. Stuffit doesn't seem to be of any help with this.

Answer (score 0):

The winzip evaluation version installed perfectly on wine, and was able to extract the archive for me. (I tried The Unarchiver, but as Kenny noted, it wouldn't extract JPEG files)